# openGTS ip and port address settings in gps device

Tags: opengts

I could able to manage to install and run the `openGts` server software on my own laptop and I have installed `pageKite tunnelling software` to replace the "http://localhost:8080" with "https://myname.pagekite.me", so that I can accesses the server remotely. Now I can able to successfully track my mobile on my own server from remotely. (I am using `gps2openGTS` client app on my android mobile)

Now i have bought `TK103A` device and i want to track my device through `openGTS` running on my laptop. What is the IP address and port address I need to set on my device?

Command i want to send from my mobile to `GPS` device as a `SMS` like below:

adminip(password) ip-address port-address

Waiting for the response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IP address should be the public IP address of your server (I guess it's given to you by Pagekite). You need to forward a separate port for your GPS device as it can't use web interface HTTP port (it needs raw TCP port). The number depends on what port OpenGTS uses for that device.